# Unable to mount NFS in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nfs, subnet

I have created a NFS volume with default config (Grant access to all clients on the VPC network) in the us-east1-b region.

I have created 15 clusters in the us-east1-b region with default network, hence when i try to create 16th cluster, i got the below exception

```
Retry budget exhausted (80 attempts) Exceeded maximum supported number of secondary ranges per subnetwork : 30.
```

Next, I created a new subnet named default-2 with a different ip range in us-east1-b region and created a cluster in the us-east1-b region with the new subnet default-2.

The problem is now with the new cluster with subnet default-2, i am unable to mount NFS into it due to timeout issue.

Will you please provide a suggestion for this problem as even after google search, i am unable to find the right solution for this